# Area Calculator in 3D models - Autodesk Forge

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

Is there a way to calculate Area in 3D Viewer?

[image: for example:]

Answer (score 0):

That depends on several factors:

- if you are manually placing a [BoxGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry) into the 3D scene (similarly to inserting rectangles in a 2D drawing), you can get the area/volume of the box from its width, height, and depth
- if you are looking for the area of some irregular objects (such as floors) in a Revit model or an IFC model, metrics like area/volume are usually available in the metadata
- if you are interested in areas of generic faces of objects in your model, that's possible as well, but more involved; Forge Viewer allows you to get all the way down to individual triangles of your 3D objects ([blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer)), so you could compute sum up the areas of individual triangles